# bit size of int array defined using typedef

Tags: c

```
typedef unsigned int Set[10];
Set set1;
```

I am correct in assuming that this creates a variable of type Set named set1 with 320 bits of storage space?

Comment: My I suggest you consider changing you accepted answer, refp's answer covers more of the factors as to why 320 bits can not be assumed correct

Comment: changed now that his answer is more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of bits (and bytes<sup>1</sup>) allocated may vary. Though, it is guaranteed to create a sequentiell storage for 10 integers which can be references through `set1`.

---

**What does the standard say?**

The standard doesn't force a *byte* to contain `N` *bits* since that will make it harder to write compilers for a platform which doesn't have `N` *bits* in a *byte*.

> **[[open-std.org - n1147.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), 3.6/3]**
>
> - A byte is composed of a contiguous sequence of bits, **the
>     number of which is implementation deﬁned**. The least signiﬁcant bit
>     is called the low-order bit; the most signiﬁcant bit is called the
>     high-order bit.

---

#### How would I get the number of bits in type T?

There is a constant (`CHAR_BIT`) defined that holds the number of bits in a *char* in <*climits*>.

Since all types consists of *N* bytes and a *char* is guaranteed to yield 1 when doing `sizeof(char)` we can use this constraint to calculate the bits in any arbitrary type.

```
#include <climits>

template<typename T>
struct sizeof_in_bits {
  enum {
    value = sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT
  };
};
```

```
std::cerr << "output: " << sizeof_in_bits<unsigned int[10]>::value;
```

> output: 320

<sup>The above output is, as mentioned, **implementation-defined**.</sup>

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> The standard doesn't force the size of an `int` to be `M` bytes. All it cleary states is that an `int` is to be able to hold **at least** `-32767` through `32767` (if signed), and `0` to `65535` (if unsigned).</sup>

Comment: not the most well worded addition at the end, but this is definitely the better answer. It is wrong to assume an `int` will always be 4 bytes

Comment: beautiful :D now if only we could force which answer is accepted :P

Answer (score 6):

No. This creates a variable of type `Set` called `set1` that has *at least* the amount of sequential storage on the C stack required for 10 `unsigned int`'s.

How many bits those are? This will depend on the platform and compiler. You can print how many bits it are in your particular setup by writing:

```
#include <limits.h>

typedef unsigned int Set[10];

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("Set has at least %d bits.\n", sizeof(Set) * CHAR_BIT);
    return 0;
}
```